# Difference between 0 and negative value for setMaxAge for Cookie

Tags: cookies

From cookie docs for setMaxAge(int):
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge(int)
Is there any difference between `int = 0` and `int = -ve`? It says `0` deletes cookie. `-ve` value means cookie is not stored. Does that mean 0 deletes only from current browser session?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I suggest you go read about cookies from a browser perspective. It's very interesting. Note that 'max-age' is the newer version of 'expires' and some browsers may not support it. (For example, IE6, IE7, and IE8 don't support max-age.)

0 means delete the cookie right now.

negative means preserve the cookie for a while. I suspect the scope is somewhat browser specific but it will not preserve the cookie across closing and reopening the browser.

Comment: From https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265
_If delta-seconds is less than or equal to zero (0), let expiry-time be the earliest representable date and time.  Otherwise, let the expiry-time be the current date and time plus delta-seconds seconds._

Answer (score 10):

Setting setMaxAge to 0 will delete the cookie. Setting it to -1 will preserve it until the browser is closed.

Answer (score 3):

[setMaxAge(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) as mentioned by Oracle setting max age 0 will delete the cookie instantly. While -1 will delete the cookie when the browser is closed.