# jQuery: remove a cookie when closing the browser (session cookie)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

It sounds simple and I think it should be simple, but somehow I don't get it to work...

I want to set a Cookie using Javascript and this Cookie should be removed when the user quits the browser. Setting the cookie and getting the value is not the problem. But when I quit the browser and reopen it, the cookie is still there (Firefox).

I use jQuery and the [Cookie-Plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Here is my test code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#output').append( '<li>initialize...</li>' );

var $cookieVal = $.cookie('testCookie');

$('#output').append( '<li>check cookie...</li>' );

if(!$cookieVal) {
    $('#output').append( '<li>set cookie...</li>' );
    $.cookie('testCookie', 'eat cookies', { path: '/' });
    //console.log( $.cookie() );
} else {
    $('#output').append( '<li>cookie is already set...</li>' );
    $('#output').append( '<li>cookie value: '+$.cookie('testCookie')+'</li>' );
}
});
```

Please find the working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5HTr/2/).

Comment: Did you try removing it on the unload event? http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: Your code doesn't attempt to remove the cookie anywhere.

Comment: @Lebowski156 The code shouldn't have to remove the cookie anywhere, because if you don't set an expiration date, the cookie should be removed automatically when the session ends, which is what he wants. That being said, the jsfiddle doesn't work for me anyway. `var $cookieVal = $.cookie('testCookie');` doesn't work cause it says there is no method `cookie`.

Comment: This has some info on cookies. Setting a negative maxage means it will die at the end of the session: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932957/difference-between-0-and-negative-value-for-setmaxage-for-cookie/15933185#15933185

Comment: Your code works for me. See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C5HTr/4/ run it the first time and the cookie is set. Close the browser and then navigate back to the fiddle. The cookie is set again.

Comment: In Opera on Mac it works for me as well. But not in Firefox... :-(

Comment: @Gray You are exactly right. The cookie should be removed automatically. Are you using Chrome? In Chrome it is not working at all :-(

Comment: I was using chrome. I made an alternative solution cause I was curious that does not use the cookie library. see: http://jsfiddle.net/8Ahg2/ In fact, it doesn't even really need jQuery, just plain js.

Comment: @Gray Hmm, this is not workling for me. When I close Firefox (on Mac) and start it again, the cookie is still there...

Comment: @chris very weird. Are you 100% sure you don't have any other windows open? If you have ANY browser windows open, it will persist the cookie.

Comment: @Gray yes, I am 100% sure. Is it a problem, that Firefox opens up all tabs again? Does that mean, that it recovers the old session? In Safari it does not write the cookie at all. By the way: what is the fancy regular expression doing?

Comment: It could be that when firefox does that, it is in fact "restoring the session" (hence, the session cookies remaining). I haven't used FF much in a while, is that an extension or setting doing that? Not sure why it doesn't work in Safari since it works in Chrome/FF for me. regex gets the cookie value out. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Comment: @Gray It drives me crazy. I have now tried Chrome with your jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8Ahg2/). The ourput is always the same: "cookie value: test", which means, the cookie was not removed when quiting Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am beginning to wonder if your testing method might be the problem here. So, I am going to write this in a specific way.

#### Actual Answer: Browser Setting

In Firefox, Options>General>When Firefox starts>"Show my windows and tabs from last time"  is going to preserve your previous session. Change this setting to see that this is indeed working as it is supposed to. Firefox is prolonging your session. For further information, see this "bug": http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=530594

There are similar settings in most browsers that probably behave the same way.

---

### Original Answer:

I created a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/8Ahg2/ that uses document.cookie rather than jquery cookie plugin. Here is how you test this. (source below)

1. copy the following URL to your clipboard: `http://fiddle.jshell.net/8Ahg2/show/`
2. **Completely** close your browser of choice - this should be browser independent.
3. Open your browser, paste the url. The first time it should say: `check cookie...
   set cookie...`
4. Refresh the page, notice that it should now say the value of the cookie ("test")
5. Close your browser **completely** again.
6. Navigate to the URL that should still be in your clipboard. ***Do not refresh the page** on the first view, it should again say '`check cookie...
   set cookie...`'

---

#### js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#output').append('<li>initialize...</li>');
    //this regex gets the "name" cookie out of the string of cookies that look like this: "name=test;var2=hello;var3=world"
    var cookieVal = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)name\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");

    $('#output').append('<li>check cookie...</li>');

    if (!cookieVal) {
        $('#output').append('<li>set cookie...</li>');
        document.cookie = "name=test";
    } else {
        $('#output').append('<li>cookie is already set...</li>');
        $('#output').append('<li>cookie value: ' + cookieVal + '</li>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I am following exactly your steps, but when I open the brwoser again, the cookie is still there. Is it working for everybody else?

Comment: @chris Let me ask you this. In Firefox, since that is the browser we share. Open `Options>General>When Firefox starts` Does yours say "Show my windows and tabs from last time"? If so, it is going to preserve your previous session. Change this setting to (hopefully) see that this is indeed working as it is supposed to. Firefox is prolonging your session from what I can tell.

Comment: If this fixes your issue, check out this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=530594 for some more information possibly. You most likely have a similar setting set in Safari/Chrome if that happens for you there as well.

Comment: Wow, that was the problem... When I change the settings, it works like I expected it to work. Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: I'd like to confirm here that it's not working for me in Chrome either.

Comment: @red, are you saying you have the same issue as the OP and the directions in my answer did not help? Does it only happen in Chrome? Try IE or Firefox. If it only happens in Chrome, look for the setting I talked about in the answer - you probably have a similar one set.

Comment: I'm sorry I initially misunderstood your solution as a workaround to the setting. My bad! However, I'm seeing some weird behaviour in IE9, will comment again soon.

Comment: Alright, I was working based on your exact code at http://jsfiddle.net and it did not work, but for some reason it did function over at http://fiddle.jshell.net -- and this was only affecting IE9. Not sure what could have caused it but works now.

Comment: Check this out in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/CyrGf/21/embedded/result/ vs. http://fiddle.jshell.net/CyrGf/21/embedded/result/ - Pretty weird, 'eh?

Comment: Weird. Glad it works - I couldn't reproduce your issue on my end - maybe some security policy with iframes and cookies? No idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is some code that worked for me. It should expire when you close the browser because of the date to expire being before now:

```
    var vEnd = new Date();
    vEnd.setDate(vEnd.getDate() - 1);
    var endOfCookieText = "; expires=" + vEnd.toGMTString() + ";  path=/";
    document.cookie = escape('testCookie') + "=" + escape("eat cookies") + endOfCookieText;
```

[FIDDLE MODIFIED](http://jsfiddle.net/C5HTr/6/)

Note that the fiddle gives a bunch of load errors on the console for me.

Comment: Strange, this is not working for me on Firefox and Safari on Mac.