# Maxage of my cookie is reset to -1

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, cookies

I am trying to create a cookie and set its max age.
i am using set Comment and set Max Age method to set the same.

```
HttpSession browserSession = httpRequest.getSession();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("SESSION", browserSession.getId());
cookie.setComment("test");
cookie.setMaxAge(Integer.MAX_VALUE);     
httpResponse.addCookie(cookie);
```

but when i fetch cookies form Request and then i debug it, comment is null and max age of cookie is -1, the cookie name i am setting as SESSION.
why is this happening?

Comment: I suspect you need a `CookieManager` object to do this properly.  C# is the same; it requires a `CookieContainer` object.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/accessingCookies.html

Comment: Also, note that setting a *signed* integer to Integer.MAX_VALUE will most likely result in a -1, if `Integer` is unsigned.  See http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?decimal=045049

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15932957

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. Take into account that max-age applies to a client-side, but clients will only send to server the pair name value.

So, if you set "3600" to your cookie and add it to the response, you should see that on the cookie from the client side, but the cookie contained on the very next request will show you, probably, -1, on the server side.

See [RFC6265 4.2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-4.2)  for further information.